# Как поставить курсор в поле панели searchControl - Яндекс карт?

Tags: яндекс-карты

Необходимо, после загрузки карты, поставить курсор в панель поиска! Нигде в документации и прочих местах не нашел подобную информацию? Скажите такой метод вообще существует?

Спасибо